# Unity3d text overlay interchanges after rotation

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

To create a drop shadow effect of 3dText in Unity, i have added 2 text components over each other.

But when i rotate them, for some of the characters the z-index of the shadow changes and it comes in the front.

I read somewhere that in case of drop shadows by my method we need to tell the sequence of the render pipeline.But i'm unable to find that information too.

Please help in how i can efficiently stop the error of changing z-index

Comment: If you use your own text shader, you can [set its render order](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/SL-SubshaderTags.html) like so: `Tags { "Queue" = "Geometry+1" }`.

Comment: Thanks, I would have also accepted it as answer